# Resetting a custom made color table

Tags: ocean, petrel

I have made some custom property versions with corresponding custom color tables. Everything seems to work quite well. However, when I select "Reset the color table" in the color tab, Petrel does not set the values to my default values, but to some unknown color sceme.

Does anyone know how it is possible to make Petrel reset to my custom made color table default values? This is on Ocean 2010.

Best regards
Odd Marius Aakervik
Blueback Reservoir AS

Answer (score 3):

The Reset color table button on the Petrel interface will set the color table to the Petrel default for the template associated with your Property. You cannot use this button to reset colors to a custom property version. What you need is a custom template. This is not available in 2010. In the meantime, you can introduce a context menu entry on the Property objects to set the object's color table to your default... or wait for the next version of Petrel.